# PHP Query not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem that is staring me in the face but I cannot seem to solve it.

First of:

1) the code is parsed prior to check for SQL injection.
2) $dbc is a reference that is part of another script that is "require_once()" called in and is working perfectly as its fine for 2 other scripts depending on it
3) the query text when pumped straight into mysql calls back exactly what Im after
4) If I put a false array into $displayBlogs, the rest of script acts as it should.

The table is populated. So why do I seem to receive no results, no errors (checked with mysqli_error($dbc) ) ? Blogs just seems to be empty.

```
function getSnippets()
{
  // set up the query   
  $query1 = "SELECT * FROM blogs LIMIT 0, 10";

  // action the query and save the connection
  $blogs = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1);

  // blank out the variable that will be used to save the query results
  $displayBlogs = '';

  // iterate through the query results and set up the module return
  while($blog = mysqli_fetch_array($blogs))
  {
    $displayBlogs .= "<div class='article'><a href='" . $blog['link'] ."'>" .
                     "<h1>" . $blog['title'] . "</h1>" .
                     "<h2>" . $blog['date'] . "</h2>" .
                     "<p>" . $blog['body'] . "</p>" .
                     "</a></div>";
  }      
  return $displayBlogs;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare global scope for $dbc :

```
function getSnippets()
{
    global $dbc;
    // declaring $dbc global to have it accessed outside the scope of the function
}
```

or, even **better**, pass it as an argument of the function, as using global variables is considered **bad** practice (check, among many, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why) SO question as for why):

```
function getSnippets($dbc)
{
   $connection = $dbc;
   //...
   $blogs = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);

  // rest of code...
}
```

Comment: This this was it! I just passed the variable to the function and hey preseto!

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's required, the `$dbc` variable shouldn't be accesable from inside a function. To make it posible, [use it as a global](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php).

In that case, it'd be written, at the start, you should write:

```
function getSnippets()
{
    global $dbc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to `global $dbc;`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using var_dump() on each of the variables used till you nail the culprit.

```
$dbc
$query1
$blogs
$blog
```

Also, you should be monitoring your mysql logs to see what, if anything, is actually happening at the database end.

Not solving your issue I realise (pretty sure Scott got that) but hopefully leading you to isolate and identify similar errors in the future (you will make them).